# Do I use is/are with measurements and time?

Tags: verbs

EX:

There is/are 12 months in year
There is/are 60 minutes in an hour
etc.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U Ananymous.  Your question will be well received at http://ell.stackexchange.com/ our sister site for students of English.

Comment: If it's contracted (which it almost always is in speech), _there's_ works for singular and plural. If you insist on spelling out the auxiliary verb, then you have to inflect it for singular or plural. Your choice.

Answer (score 3):

12 months and 60 minutes are countable. so you need to use **are**